# Mysql commaseparated column matching from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select all matches from a commaseparated column in table2, where column could be like this: 0,1,2 OR 2,4,5 OR 2,5 OR 1,3,5 etc.

I have tried with:

```
SELECT * from table where 1,3,5 IN(SELECT commaseparated FROM table2) WHERE ..
```

But error on statement when using commas.

I've also tried using REGEXP but in my case i need to search for all matches within 1,3,5

How can i solve this one? :)

Comment: you can't do that you have to explode the contents of the database and convert them to string or array and use that to search.

Comment: you need to do `where 1 IN(...) and 2 IN (...) and 3 IN(...)`

Comment: Posting the whole query and the error you get would make it easier to solve your problem

Comment: You could also normalize your database and not save a comma-separated list as one column. Use a seperate table with foreign keys. This would make your query way easier und more efficient.

Comment: Just to be sure: There are no comma-separated list types in MySQL, so I assume `commaseparated` is of type string. You don't want `SELECT * from mytable where '1,3,5' IN(SELECT commaseparated FROM table2)`, do you? (added quotes around your list, to make it a string)

Comment: I think i better normalise database, because i will run into this problem again and again :) Learnt my lesson here..

Thanks so much for help all!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't do that in standard SQL. it's

```
   WHERE singlevalue IN (list, of, values)
```

if you want to compare lists against lists, you should revamp your tables so they're properly normalized. Storing formatted data in a field basically negates the purpose of having a relational database - you can't establish relationships with the data if it's not in a format that allows relationships to be formed.

If those CSV lists were in sub-tables, you could do a very simple JOIN query to meet your specifications.